# Can inline constructors use initialization lists in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, inline, initializer-list

I've been digging through the source code of an API and I noticed lack of usage of initialization lists, which was instead moved to the constructor body. I thought this is suboptimal but then noticed that those constructors are inline.

So is there some limitation when using initialization lists with inline constructors?
10x

Comment: Well, did _you_ try a simple code to figure out?

Comment: There is no such restriction.

Comment: I wish I could, I am currently mobile and have no access to a C++ compiler, I just put some source code on my tablet so I can analyze it while I am away from home.

Comment: @GradGuy How would that help?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Well often times it's faster to try something simple to figure things out rather asking them, don't you think?

Comment: @GradGuy I think that a compiler would just tell you if it accepts the syntax, but is in no way a guarantee that the code is actually valid. Compilers are not standard-compliant and they shouldn't be used as validators for code.

Comment: @GradGuy - If I was at home that would be the first thing to do, but then it will be just to myself, and having this question answered here might be of use to many other people, since I didn't seem to find it answered already.

Comment: @ddriver Well, I'm not opposed to asking -- SO _is_ the place to ask. But then again I'm more of a do-first ask-later kinda of person.

Comment: Yes, I am a do first, ask questions if it doesn't work type of person too, and even thou in most cases this is faster, in this case it would take days before I have access to a C++ compiler, and the answer I got here was almost as fast as it would have been if I tested it myself.

Comment: Better put a copy of the standard on your tablet :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no limitation, initialization lists can be used same as before.

Also, I doubt there's any performance loss. Inline constructors means that the compiler can better optimize the code, since it's visible to all translation units that use that class.

From a coding-style point of view, they should have used initialization lists.